# How do I check if I have root access?

Tags: linux, root

My boss want his team members to let him know, who has root access.

How do I check if I have root access?

If I can login on a server and do anything with `sudo`, does it mean I have root access?

Comment: Simple answer: Yes.

Comment: If you can do *anything* with `sudo`, you're either in the `wheel` group or your user has a specific entry in `sudoers`. If you can only do *some* things with `sudo`, that means there's some careful `sudoers` settings going on.

Answer (score 34):

Yes. If you are able to use `sudo` to run any command (for example `passwd` to change the root password), you definitely have root access.

If you, for example, run `sudo -s` and it gives you a shell, you may issue the `id` command.  It will respond with something like

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

A UID of 0 (zero) means "root", always.

Your boss would be happy to have a list of the users listed in the `/etc/sudoers` file. If there are groups listed in there, he would probably want to know who the members of those groups are.

For example, if the system has a `sudo` (and/or `admin`/`wheel`) group which is listed in the `sudoers` file like

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

This gives free rein to any member of the group `sudo` to use `sudo` without restriction.

This is how you get all the usernames of that group:

```bash
grep '^sudo' /etc/group
```

Alternatively,

```bash
getent group sudo
```

on systems using LDAP or NIS/YP, or some other directory service.